# How to make a quick response similar to messenger in Dilos flow for the default section

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I need to make quick replies appear, such as facebook messenger with dialog flow for my web page. In facebook messenger I did it with a template in the custom payload, but in the default section this template does not work, and although I have investigated I can only find that it is not possible. I want to know if anyone knows how to do it.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Please also share screenshots of what you’ve tried to help us with solving your issue.